# How to read dbf file in sas?

Tags: sas

I want to read dbf file in sas. 
But , I try the following code which can't run .

My sas edition is SAS/STAT 13.2

```
proc import out = test
    datafile = "mypath\filename.dbf"
    dbms=dbf
    replace ;
run
```

it showed "ERROE : DBMS type DBF not valid import"

Therefore , I try another code.

```
proc dbf
```

it showed "ERROR : Procedure DBF not found"

Comment: SAS/Stat version 13.2 was released with SAS version 9.4m2 back in 2014.  Can you update to a newer version of SAS?  Also run PROC SETINIT to see if you have licensed SAS/Access Interface to PC Files.

Comment: I used proc setinit . It showed that "SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC " . Is it the same with "SAS/Access Interface to PC Files"? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please, check which SAS Interface to PC Files version you using. [DBF](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103773.htm) is available for >=9.3 versions.
If you have version below, try to find solution that fits your SAS version, or provide your version here, so we can help you.

Comment: My SAS version is 9.4M2 . Can it be available to read DBF file ? Thank you !

Comment: You might check with proc setinit if pc files are avaible

Comment: I suggest you first confirm that SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files is in your current licence - `proc setinit`.

If it is included then you may need to go through the install again selecting SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files as an additional product.

If it is not - you do not have SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files.